# semanticContentAttribute is not working anymore with default UITableViewCells

Tags: swift, ios11

I have a running app, and I'm trying to add RTL language support.

I use the line below in my `AppDelegate` to execute after start, specifically in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

It was working perfectly on iOS 10, but now on iOS 11, the default tableView cell's **labels** are still aligned LTR.

[image: current behavior]

Comment: You should set the label alignment as `natural` instead of `left`. Label alignment is effected by `semanticContentAttribute` *only* if its `textAlignmnet` is `natural`, otherwise it apply the assigned value.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the label's semantic content attribute to `.forceRightToLeft` as well.

### Programmatically

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: <your cell ID>, for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

    return cell
}
```

### In Interface Builder

1. Select **the text label** of the cell.

   [image: text label of cell selected]
2. Open **the Attributes inspector** (the fourth icon from the left) from the toolbar on the right.

   [image: Attributes inspector selected]
3. In the **View** section, set the **Semantic** option to **Force Right-to-Left**.

   [image: Semantic set to Force Right-to-Left]

### Result

[image: cell with right-aligned text]

Comment: Yea.. I know, but I cannot afford doing that for all the tableViews that I have. I want something to fix all those labels at once.

Comment: So Gazara how did you handle it eventually, i need to solve this now :D

Comment: @Alshcompiler, I didn't find a way to fix it all over the app.
Either always have a custom cell. Or create a BaseCell that handles this for you.